# Python nested list: How to split the inner string elements of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, nested-lists

Assuming I have a list, which contains string elements. How can I split the string element of every cell of every index of the list, without having them all mixed up with each other? I still want every element separated from the one in the other indexes. Is this possible?
For example, if I have this input from the user:

```
user_input = ['hello', 'hey', 'hi']
```

How can I make it look like this:

```
split_list = [['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], ['h', 'e', 'y'], ['h', 'i']]
```

Comment: Don't make use imagine what you do, provide code and examples please

Comment: @azro Ok sorry, I just added an example. I thought I was being clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, so split on every character, the way is using the `list` constructor, so every element of the given input is treated as a value of the list. Combinate that with a list comprehension and you're done

```
user_input = ['hello', 'hey', 'hi']
split_list = [list(x) for x in user_input]
```

Comment: I find your solution the simplest. I appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list function on a string to split the string into a list containing each of its characters.

```
>>> strings = ['some', 'strings', 'here']
>>> list(map(lambda x: list(x), strings))
[['s', 'o', 'm', 'e'], ['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 's'], ['h', 'e', 'r', 'e']]
```

Comment: `map(lambda x: list(x), strings)` -> `map(list, strings)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split by a string like you would with the .split() function, you could loop through the elements in the array.

```
test_list = ["String 1", "String 2"]

def split_list(input_list, delimiter):
    for i in range(len(input_list)):
        input_list[i] = input_list[i].split(delimiter)

    return input_list

print(split_list(test_list, " "))

Returns: [['String', '1'], ['String', '2']]
```

Comment: No, I don't want it word by word. I want it character by character.